# trying to position my buttons centre screen with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Looked up various articles and answers on this site,a popular answer of which seems to be to use `<div class="text-center">`, but it didn't work for me. The button starts on the very left of the screen. Any idea how it could be done - keeping it within bootstrap, ideally, instead of having to put new classes in my style sheets. Thanks.

Code I have right now is:

```
                <div class="text-center">
                  <%= image_tag 'logo_for_web.png'  %>
  <h3>Header here</h3>

  <h4>
                    Text here
  </h4>

    <h4>
                    Text here
  </h4>

    <%= link_to "Sign up", '#', class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-11" %>

    <%= link_to "Log in with Facebook", '#', class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-11" %>
    <%= link_to "Log in with email", '#', class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-11" %>
    <%= link_to "Use without signing up", '#', class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-11" %>
    <%= link_to "About Us", { controller: "static_pages", action: "about"}, class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-11" %>
    <%= link_to "Contact Us", '#', class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-11" %>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use grids, and align them center. Bootstrap has total 12 grid columns. So;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <!-- Your Buttons Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm specialising my app for mobile so I think col-xs is more appropriate, right? Anyway, you put me on the right track...

Comment: Yup; `col-xs` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

What I used eventually was (my app is being made primarily for mobile):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 ">
        <%= link_to "Log in with Facebook", '#', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
        <%= link_to "Log in with email", '#', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", '#', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
        <%= link_to "Use without signing up", '#', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
        <%= link_to "About Us", { controller: "static_pages", action: "about"}, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
        <%= link_to "Contact Us", '#', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```